# Does iOS app crashes when its distribution profile's status changes to "invalid"?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store, testflight

I have developed an iOS app which is successfully published to testflight and sent to testing.

Users installed app and tested on respective iOS devices. But after some days whenever we are trying to open app it crashes immediately within splash of a second.

I found that my distribution profile status changed to invalid. I again generated it and status changed to active. I deleted old app before changing the status to active again. So unable to verify if that causes the issue.

Any idea? It is a serious problem because what if my app goes live and if profile becomes invalid?

thanks

Below is crash report which I found on Xcode:

```
Incident Identifier: 4FE651F7-754C-481E-9591-5281E5E2B3AD
Beta Identifier:     073228CB-18D2-456A-A322-7A7CFFC33ED0
Hardware Model:      iPhone10,3
Process:             TCRMobile.iOS [7717]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4C97A946-CF53-4A81-AA25-688EC6E7EECF/TCRMobile.iOS.app/TCRMobile.iOS
Identifier:          com.tcrsoftware.xamuinotifapple
Version:             5.0 (1.1)
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.tcrsoftware.xamuinotifapple [1637]


Date/Time:           2018-08-27 13:37:09.1179 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-08-27 13:37:08.3911 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4.1 (15G77)
Baseband Version:    1.93.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4307222528
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000100bb0000-0000000100bb4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...TCRMobile.iOS

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826192e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827be6a8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$armv81 + 360 (pthread.c:1484)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182587db0 __abort + 152 (abort.c:128)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000182587d18 abort + 152 (abort.c:99)
4   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010260a888 xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 36 (runtime.m:1135)
5   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001025145b4 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 132 (exception.c:1085)
6   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024cc6c8 mono_handle_exception_internal + 4580 (mini-exceptions.c:1995)
7   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024cb4d8 mono_handle_exception + 40 (mini-exceptions.c:2282)
8   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024c30e8 mono_arm_throw_exception + 240 (exceptions-arm64.c:409)
9   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100f2b2c8 throw_exception + 168
10  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000101a6fb80 TCRMobile_App_LoadApp + 608 (App.xaml.cs:96)
11  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000101a6f8f8 TCRMobile_App__ctor_string_int + 440 (App.xaml.cs:49)
12  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100c1c750 TCRMobile_iOS_AppDelegate_FinishedLaunching_UIKit_UIApplication_Foundation_NSDictionary + 320 (/<unknown>:1)
13  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100ef9524 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
14  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024dc44c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824 (mini-runtime.c:2767)
15  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102557b44 do_runtime_invoke + 108 (object.c:2862)
16  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102557aa4 mono_runtime_invoke + 208 (object.c:3016)
17  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100bf443c native_to_managed_trampoline_33(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, UIApplication*, NSDictionary*, unsigned int) + 496 (registrar.m:1489)
18  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100bf49d8 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 60 (registrar.m:10598)
19  UIKit                           0x000000018c7a1dbc -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 408 (UIApplication.m:1804)
20  UIKit                           0x000000018c7a11c4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3484 (UIApplication.m:2172)
21  UIKit                           0x000000018c76e5e0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1680 (UIApplication.m:3491)
22  UIKit                           0x000000018cd9eb1c __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 784 (_UICanvasLifecycleMonitor.m:175)
23  UIKit                           0x000000018c76ddd0 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160 (_UICanvas.m:591)
24  UIKit                           0x000000018c76dc6c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 240 (_UICanvasLifecycleMonitor.m:153)
25  UIKit                           0x000000018c76cafc -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 724 (_UICanvasLifecycleMonitor.m:229)
26  UIKit                           0x000000018d40284c __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 296 (_UIApplicationCanvas.m:0)
27  UIKit                           0x000000018c76c1ec -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 432 (_UIApplicationCanvas.m:156)
28  UIKit                           0x000000018d1e7ac8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220 (_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:211)
29  UIKit                           0x000000018d335bf8 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112 (_UICanvasSettingsDiffAction.m:34)
30  UIKit                           0x000000018c76bc0c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 248 (_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction.m:182)
31  UIKit                           0x000000018c76b5a8 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 368 (_UICanvas.m:517)
32  UIKit                           0x000000018c7685e0 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540 (UIApplication.m:3109)
33  UIKit                           0x000000018c768330 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364 (UIApplicationSceneClientAgent.m:41)
34  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000185394470 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364 (FBSSceneImpl.m:460)
35  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018539cd6c __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224 (FBSWorkspace.m:606)
36  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182484a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:507)
37  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001824c0b2c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$armv81 + 216 (queue.c:3018)
38  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001853c8878 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36 (FBSSerialQueue.m:164)
39  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001853c851c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404 (FBSSerialQueue.m:196)
40  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001853c8ab8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56 (FBSSerialQueue.m:232)
41  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3b404 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
42  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3ac2c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
43  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3879c __CFRunLoopRun + 1204 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
44  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a58da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
45  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184a3e020 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
46  UIKit                           0x000000018ca78758 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3965)
47  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000101848970 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 368 (/<unknown>:1)
48  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001017c127c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 44 (UIApplication.cs:79)
49  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001017c123c UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 172 (UIApplication.cs:63)
50  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100c1c524 TCRMobile_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 36 (/<unknown>:1)
51  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100ef9524 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 244
52  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024dc44c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 824 (mini-runtime.c:2767)
53  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102557b44 do_runtime_invoke + 108 (object.c:2862)
54  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010255ade8 do_exec_main_checked + 144 (object.c:3016)
55  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001024bf934 mono_jit_exec + 268 (driver.g.c:1036)
56  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001026115c8 xamarin_main + 1108 (monotouch-main.m:483)
57  TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000100c1c3b4 main + 96 (main.m:155)
58  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001824e9fc0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182619d78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000182619d78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826190e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827bfed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000181cd02ec std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 96 (__threading_support:284)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a1e16e8 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 124 (__mutex_base:0)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a1e1598 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 112 (condition_variable:226)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a1e10dc bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 272 (condition_variable:237)
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a1e0e18 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 12 (Scavenger.cpp:143)
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018a1e1234 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scavenger*> >(void*) + 44 (type_traits:4323)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001825f7de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001825f7c60 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b38908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a58da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   WebCore                         0x000000018ad1c2d4 RunWebThread(void*) + 592 (WebCoreThread.mm:624)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826190e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827bfed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001025d90e8 thread_func + 572 (mono-os-mutex.h:173)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001825f7e24 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001025158d4 finalizer_thread + 332 (mono-os-semaphore.h:91)
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102585714 start_wrapper + 604 (threads.c:829)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b04 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2458)

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001825f7de8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001825f7c60 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b3ae40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b38908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182a58da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001834cd674 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001834cd51c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
7   UIKit                           0x000000018c75d768 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:437)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001835ddefc __NSThread__start__ + 1040 (NSThread.m:1181)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b04 start_wqthread + 0 (pthread.c:2458)

Thread 10 name:
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826190e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827bfed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x00000001025ee858 mono_thread_info_sleep + 764 (mono-os-mutex.h:216)
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010257b09c monitor_thread + 960 (threadpool-worker-default.c:693)
4   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102585714 start_wrapper + 604 (threads.c:829)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826190e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827bfed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010257b698 worker_thread + 916 (mono-os-mutex.h:216)
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102585714 start_wrapper + 604 (threads.c:829)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001826190e8 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827bfed8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$armv81 + 628 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x000000010257b698 worker_thread + 916 (mono-os-mutex.h:216)
3   TCRMobile.iOS                   0x0000000102585714 start_wrapper + 604 (threads.c:829)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9220 _pthread_body + 272 (pthread.c:740)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b9110 _pthread_start + 292 (pthread.c:799)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001827b7b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x00000001d42e7300   x7: 0x00000000000024dc
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x00000001b7491e44
   x12: 0x00000001b7491e44  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b50e3b40  x21: 0x000000016f24bb48  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b50e3c20
   x24: 0x000000012be01260  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x000000012c01f600  x27: 0x0000000100ef9523
   x28: 0x0000000000010001   fp: 0x000000016f24b070   lr: 0x00000001827be6a8
    sp: 0x000000016f24b040   pc: 0x00000001826192e0 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x100bb0000 - 0x10286ffff TCRMobile.iOS arm64  <9207b7c6ab483a41aed1645b77d828f5> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4C97A946-CF53-4A81-AA25-688EC6E7EECF/TCRMobile.iOS.app/TCRMobile.iOS
0x102cbc000 - 0x102cf7fff dyld arm64  <b15e536a710732dabfafece44c5685e4> /usr/lib/dyld
0x181cc7000 - 0x181cc8fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <0f3f5f4ea60d3d4d84af311421f67108> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x181cc9000 - 0x181d21fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <e6172d25b5d63239879410136730d916> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x181d22000 - 0x181d43fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <40c62b02df253630845890510fe3f773> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x181d44000 - 0x1823fffff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <eb1135b2bde93b69b96e42ca98200183> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x182400000 - 0x182405fff libcache.dylib arm64  <a922e78994f33bb6a85162f25a9c7965> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x182406000 - 0x182411fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <d3ccb275f62c361bba490fa6a9bb383c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x182412000 - 0x182415fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <82d8312d934c3f34b74d8df84e2cb55c> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x182416000 - 0x18241efff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <e07dded07d6f375d8fabfa20b0d5f6b5> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x18241f000 - 0x182482fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <68071da426b335bb860aed1483e03d6e> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x182483000 - 0x1824e8fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <0c931ac760133de187bb6f440beed5eb> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1824e9000 - 0x182503fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <6225b1cd39843071a64add8f31b09c36> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x182504000 - 0x182504fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <a25d2deb6e2d3c09a1085a5a79b16fdc> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x182505000 - 0x18250afff libmacho.dylib arm64  <797e8ee3e3b83978aaae2394e71ea6c3> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x18250b000 - 0x18250cfff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <a454faf6fd5e3f2fa3116507d634a357> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18250d000 - 0x182523fff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <833790f7db363b8e83b48eaec404a8aa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x182524000 - 0x182524fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <a7c74cd6406f37d7a6beeb8faa6e1706> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x182525000 - 0x1825a2fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <61d2e950add73139aea459b55997ea48> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1825a3000 - 0x1825a7fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <fc25fa74aabf399e9fa32acb529a8618> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x1825a8000 - 0x1825adfff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <db5dee3b17323c8aa68659a9c8dc9e76> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x1825ae000 - 0x1825affff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <64e24927a95a3b38a92af824aa262df3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x1825b0000 - 0x1825b1fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <98cca712d0a63a819653681c52131ea2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1825b2000 - 0x1825b8fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <1b83bbfe437639dd8bdb7353013ac147> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x1825b9000 - 0x1825f6fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <ebd778a7210c37408ee490f4564d4f5b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1825f7000 - 0x18261ffff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <e102701ef8803cd4a5d54f5f14433dbd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x182620000 - 0x18264dfff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <3f43e403c5983d39ab50fa375c5c1bc9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x18264e000 - 0x182669fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <6dd6981adef530b3b6062f29ade13bb2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x18266a000 - 0x182795fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <9ec043d8cb2538dc9ba84e324cd5b416> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x182796000 - 0x1827a1fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <7ed92c1b09023da8adac8c5073ca7566> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x1827a2000 - 0x1827acfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <6400d5b3305b3f5d9d831e03e357943b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1827ad000 - 0x1827b6fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <97dae109bad63e588e5d63b8dbddadcf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1827b7000 - 0x1827c6fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <07c87e3874b73d128f0fa331d8894b97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1827c7000 - 0x1827cafff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <5e76af73b50438c6b6a4827b7fb0b816> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1827cb000 - 0x1827d2fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <1a4f281f874131f68e00580a8110d629> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1827d3000 - 0x1827e6fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <38618bae31eb39cfbfd4aa0e8df9e51b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps distributed via App Store/Testflight should work just fine even if the certificates used to distribute them get revoked. The caveat here is for apps distributed via Ad Hoc or Enterprise - apps distributed using either of these methods **will** fail after revoking their certificates.

As far as finding the root cause of your crashes in the future, I highly suggest a framework such as Fabric's [Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/overview.html) or using Xcode's Organizer and viewing the Crashes tab. (Can be found in Window>Organizer when in Xcode)

Comment: Hi Kyle H.. can you please look the above crash report from xcode.

Comment: @sai Investigating the actual bug is kind of a separate question. At first glance it seems to be a Xamarin issue as I see `xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler`. Possibly asking a new question and try getting some Xamarin users to weigh in (I've never used it before personally) may help.

Comment: but this i see only this one error in xcode at different time. And the continous crash happened at different time. I think the above crash  report is not related to this crash.

Comment: I am building .IPA file by selecting distribution profile, and by using xcode im uploading it to app store. Am I doing any wrong here?

Comment: @sai There's a pretty significant chance that is is related to the issue you described as it happens at app launch, which you can see in the stack trace that the unhandled exception is right after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called.

Comment: @sai As far as your comment about the upload process, sounds like you're doing everything correctly! May want to test running to a device as well to see if you can reproduce the crash.